# Accidentally installed Ubuntu as Legacy mode while Windows (Pre-installed) as UEFI mode

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, 20.04, uefi

Please bear with my storytelling as I am not sure the errors that I encountered is related to my question.

Recently, I have installed Ubuntu in my HDD (Disk 0) with root partition (200GB), swap partition (5GB) and home partition (220GB). I did not create a new partition for EFI, in which I think I should. I read some online websites and they did mention to have a EFI partition for each disk for dual-booting. However, I took the risk to just choose SSD as my boot loader during installation of Ubuntu 20.04. Then, I encountered an error when the installation is almost done. I ignored it and forcefully install it again. Surprising (I don't know why), Ubuntu 20.04 is successfully installed.

[Allocation of spaces/partitions in my 128GB SSD (Disk 1) and 1000GB HDD (Disk 0)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qAIab.png)

After rebooting my laptop, I encountered this problem (https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/259069/how-to-start-a-windows-partition-from-the-grub-command-line/259072), in which I just enter the command `exit` to boot Windows. I am still able to access Ubuntu when I press `shift` + restart to access the GNU GRUB menu. However, I found out that my Ubuntu is installed in Legacy mode by typing the command `[ -d /sys/firmware/efi ] && echo "EFI boot on HDD" || echo "Legacy boot on HDD"`. When I check the boot order from UEFI Firmware Settings, it only shows Windows Boot Manager. So, I am confirmed that my Ubuntu is in Legacy mode.

My main concerns are:

1. Now that my Ubuntu is in Legacy mode, can I follow this link (https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UEFI#Converting_Ubuntu_into_UEFI_mode) to convert Ubuntu into UEFI mode for dual-booting without affecting my Data(D:) partition? As far as I know, when I wanted to create a EFI partition on my HDD during Ubuntu installation, it requires me to reformat everything in HDD. So, does the converting method above will delete/affect/reformat my files in Data(D:) partition?
2. If the converting method above does affect my files in Data(D:) partition and I choose to stay as Legacy mode for Ubuntu, will there be any problems on my laptop in the future?
3. Or should I just uninstall and install Ubuntu again, and create a EFI partition on HDD during the installation of Ubuntu to make things simple?

*I still want to preserve my Data(D:) in HDD for storing files in Windows.

Please feel free to comment. I apologize in advance if my question is not delivered properly.

Comment: Are both drives gpt or only the Windows drive? UEFI prefers gpt, and Windows requires gpt for UEFI boot, but Ubuntu will install in UEFI or BIOS boot mode to either gpt or MBR(msdos).  Post this in question above. `sudo parted -l`. Reinstall and conversion to gpt will typically erase drive. You should have good backups. But you can use gdisk to convert and may not lose data. But have to at minimum reinstall UEFI grub. Converting to or from GPT - must have good backups.
http://www.rodsbooks.com/gdisk/mbr2gpt.html

Comment: @oldfred both drives are gpt. I am new to Ubuntu and I am not sure how does gpt relate to my question. Maybe you can explain in a more understandable way?

Comment: If it was MBR, I would suggest converting to gpt. Since gpt, you can create an ESP by shrinking any partition within the first 2TB of drive and adding the FAT32 formatted partition with esp/boot flags. Then in Boot-Repair from live installer booted in UEFI mode and using advanced mode options in Boot-Repair, choose your install & Ubuntu drive on where to install grub.  https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair & 
https://sourceforge.net/p/boot-repair/home/Home/  How you boot live installer, UEFI or BIOS is then how it installs or repairs. So always boot in UEFI mode.